# how to control the format of rails select_date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, a date picker is shown by:

```
<%= select_date @blog.date, :use_short_month => true %>
```

it is shown as 3 drop down lists, example:

```
  [2009] [Jun] [4]
```

how can I change the `[yyyy] [mmm] [d]` sequence to `[d] [mmm] [yyyy]` dynamically when the form loads? So it looks like:

```
  [4] [Jun] [2009]
```

Note: changes required to be done in `environment.rb` is considered too static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select_date(my_date, :order => [:day, :month, :year])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles into this `select_date` order in rails problem during rails 5.0, I am providing this working solution below:

Adding `class` to a rails `select_date` form helper while also configuring the order format.

```
select_date(date = Date.current, options = {:order => [:month, :day, :year]}, html_options = { class: 'form-control form-control-lg' })
```

Comment: Thanks!  That syntax was very helpful for getting the class in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `:order` option to the tag.

EG:

```
<% select_date @blog.date, :order => [:year, :month, :day] %>
```